# How do I manually calculate average session duration?

Tags: seo, google-analytics, search-engines, local-seo, google-analytics-spam

can anyone help me tell the exact formula of the average session duration where to get from? I'm having trouble finding a manual calculation of the average session duration

For example, from the google analytics report, I got an average session duration of 20 seconds. How is the manual calculation?

I've tried to calculate with this formula "Avg Session Duration = Session Duration / Sessions" but didn't find the same result

Comment: Where are you getting the data for "Session Duration" out of Google Analytics for each session?

Answer (score 1):

The formula for average session duration is:

```
Avg Session Duration = sum(Session Duration) / Sessions
```

In other words, you add up the length of all the sessions and then divide by number of sessions.

I don't think there is any way to calculate this manually in Google Analytics because Google analytics doesn't provide a list of sessions to you along with the session duration of each.  I just don't know of any report that will give you the data you need.